# Can't output an image

Tags: assets, image

just getting start with Craft, and I can't figure out why my images won't output. Any time I try to output even the path to the url of my image, I get an `internal error: Craft\AssetFileModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named [...]`.

I can successfully do this:

```twig
{% if entry.pageImage | length %}
    {% for pageImage in entry.pageImage %}
        {{ pageImage }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Which just outputs the title of the image. But I want to display the image. I was expecting to be able to be able to use `{{pageImage.getUrl()}}` or `{{pageImage.url}}` or `{{pageImage.fileName}}` but these will throw the aforementioned error. How do I output an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually display the image with

```
{% for pageImage in entry.pageImage %}
    <img src="{{ pageImage.getUrl() }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

But this only works if you enabled the public url option for the asset source. There is a light switch if those assets should have urls or not in your cp

It also has a `getImg()` function

```
/**
 * Returns an <img> tag based on this asset.
 *
 * @return \Twig_Markup|null
 */
public function getImg()
{
    if ($this->kind == 'image' && $this->getHasUrls())
    {
        $img = '<img src="'.$this->getUrl().'" width="'.$this->getWidth().'" height="'.$this->getHeight().'" alt="'.HtmlHelper::encode($this->title).'" />';
        return TemplateHelper::getRaw($img);
    }
}
```